# Regex: find all double slash after https?:// in link

Tags: regex

I have broken links in the PostgreSQL, that contains double slash after domain. For example: 
http://example1.com//path1/path2, https://example2.com/path1//path2

I use `[^(https?://)](\/\/)` regex for capturing double slashes but this expression capture first symbol before //. And when a try to replace I have follow result http://example1.co/path1/path2 and https://example2.com/path/path2 because expression capture m// in first link and 1// in second link.
See https://regex101.com/r/NhCVMz/6

I want to replace all double slash after http:// or https:// to single slash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [negative lookback](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
s/(?<!http:|https:)\/\//\//g
```

(Or, possibly easier to see with an alternate regex delimiter of `|` instead of `/`):

```
s|(?<!http:|https:)\/\/|\/|g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hk0nJp/1)

Some versions of PCRE or Perl will give you `Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<!http:|https:)///`. For those, you can make the lookback fixed width:

```
s/(?<!ttp:|tps:)\/\//\//g
```

Comment: Is there an extra `/\/`?

Comment: Replacing two `//` with one `/` with the `/` also delimiting the replacement regex, so I don't think so. Have a look at the demo.

Comment: The demo pattern is `(?<!http:|https:)\/\/`. The one in the answer is `(?<!http:|https:)\/\//\/`

Comment: Again, this is Perl or PCRE format. You could write it `|(?<!http:|https:)\/\/|\/|g`